# Database table is locked?

Tags: php, sqlite

PHP version: 5.5, SQLite version: 3.8.

The code I use:

```
try {
      $dbh = new PDO('sqlite:'.MF_DB_PATH.MF_DB_FILE);
      $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
} catch(PDOException $e) {
      $error_connecting =  "Error connecting to the database: ".$e->getMessage();
      $pre_install_error = $error_connecting;
}

$query = "INSERT INTO forms_backup SELECT * FROM forms;";
$params = array();
$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
try{
    $sth->execute($params);
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    $post_install_error .= $e->getMessage().'<br/><br/>';
}

$query = "DROP TABLE forms;";
$params = array();
try{
    $sth->execute($params);
}catch(PDOException $e) {
    $post_install_error .= $e->getMessage().'<br/><br/>';
}
```

Error message:

> SQL: [20] DROP TABLE forms; Params: 0 Query Failed:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 6 database table is locked

Comment: please share your database schema

Comment: May be error is coming when you are trying to drop the table which will be in use with some other resources

Comment: have you found a solution?